# How do I manage Partition Functions and Partition Schemes in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl, partitioning, partition

I am currently dealing with a situation where my databases have not been creating partitions automatically as they should have been. Multiple tables are multiple months behind in partitions leaving multiple months of data in a single partition. I have figured out how to resolve the issue if the partition is one month behind, but when they are more than one month behind it I run into problems with managing partition functions and schemes.

Below is the current state of the partition function and scheme. I know that once a partition is switched out to a staging table that it can be split to add a boundary (see Alter Partition Function). I am running into problems managing this alteration relative to the scheme and the "Next Used" file group that is assigned. There are currently files and file groups leading extending up to November 2022. It seems that assigning Next Used file group in Partition scheme is the equivalent of adding a single file group ( in this case file groups like partitions are set up for one month at a time). But it seems that I can only add or designate next used one file group at a time. Does this mean that for every month I am behind I will need to switch partitions from the original table to a stage table, designate the next filegroup, split the partition and then switch the partition back to the original table and then repeat this process each month at a time? If this is the case, is there a better strategy for tackling this issue?

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [PF_1] (datetime)
    AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (N'2022-01-01T00:00:00.000',
                               N'2022-02-01T00:00:00.000',
                               N'2022-03-01T00:00:00.000');

ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION PF_1 ()
    SPLIT RANGE (N'2022-04-01T00:00:00.000');

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [PS_1]
    AS PARTITION [PF_1]
    TO ([PRIMARY],
        [FG_RPT1_2022M01],
        [FG_RPT1_2022M02],
        [FG_RPT1_2022M03],
        [FG_RPT1_2022M11]);
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your proposed approach, but if you switch out/split range/rebuild/switch in, won't you be rebuilding the tail end b-tree multiple times? If that accurately describes I think you could instead switch out the too-large partition to a staging table, get your function/scheme set up the way you want, rebuild the staging table on the now correct partitioning setup, and then switch in each of the now aligned partitions from your staging table into the live table.

Comment: The latter part of your response is what I was attempting to do. Switch out to staging/ split partition/ partition the staging table using the newly altered function/ switch back to original table.  The problem is attempting to split the P function while also designating the Next Used file group in the partition scheme. The error message said I couldn't split the P function without setting the Next Used filegroup in  Partition Scheme. I know the scheme matches the function to the appropriate file and file group, but unsure how to set up p scheme properly if I can only go one group at a time.

Comment: Yeah. Each time you split a partition, you need to specify a next used file group. My mental model is that the next used FG is "consumed" by the split operation. At my last shop, I'd written powershell to automate ongoing partition maintenance which took care of that. You could do that or write some dynamic SQL to generate the alter statements for the scheme/function if this is a one-time operation.

Comment: I had a dynamic sql script that would iterate by splitting the function and then designating the next used file group. So long as I designate the next filegroup to match with the the most recent function split,  even if I iterate through 3-4 months, I don't have to keep switching partitions back and forth between stage and original table?

Comment: I think you're going to have to do _some_ partition switching. I described what I think is the most efficient route in my original comment. But you can do all of the function/scheme work while the data is in the staging table. Just make sure that the data in the table is partition aligned with the live table before you switch it back in.